# Ajax show form after submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

i'm currently using the following ajax code to submit my form:

```
 <script>
 $('#reg-form').submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission

$.post('ajaxdmsgsub.php', $(this).serialize() )
.done(function(data){
  $('#form-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $('#form-content').fadeIn('slow').html(data);

    });
})
.fail(function(){
 alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
});
});
</script>
```

form:

```
  <div id="form-content">
 <form method="post" id="reg-form" autocomplete="off"   action="ajaxdmsgsform.php">

<label>Message</label>
<textarea class="txtarea" name="message"></textarea>

 <div class="cleared"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Message" class="submitit" onclick="hide('myModal')">
</form>

</div>
```

after submit my form disappears, I want the form to reset so users can keep submitting without a refresh - i'm using this function like an instant messenger. but have no idea how to keep the form from disappearing.

Comment: Why are you using ` onclick="hide('myModal')"` ?

Comment: my form is within a modal so when they submit the modal disappears...when they try to submit a new form the modal reappears but the form within the modal isn't there.

Comment: You're replacing the form's markup with whatever is return from the ajax response.

$('#form-content').fadeIn('slow').html(data);

Comment: @Billy is right you're replacing the form with the response.

Comment: bang on!...I've removed those 2 lines and now it works!.....many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#form-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
   $('#form-content textarea, #form-content input').each(function(){
       $(this).val("");
  })
  $('#form-content').fadeIn('slow');
});
```